# SoundCloud Podcast -- non-developer query

Tags: rss, soundcloud, feedburner

I am not a developer, and I have been doing my best to get a response from SoundCloud, but it's taking a very long time (despite being a "pro" member) and I need to make a decision.

I am one of the beta SoundCloud podcasters.  SoundCloud recommends that we use Feedburner to generate the RSS we submit to iTunes.  However, my FeedBurner RSS has an issue (involving graphics) and I can't figure out how to edit the feed without killing it and starting anew there and with Apple.

In trying to figure out how to deal with Feedburner, I found the myriad of complaints and rumors suggesting Feednurner will soon be on the outs.  I then tried going with a third party service (RapidFeeds) -- importing the (valid) SoundCloud RSS wasn't working there though, and customer support has not responded in 4 days of waiting.  SoundCloud tech support says they have been having trouble with many of these 3rd party vendors.

So ... I'm back to either Feedburner -- which, unless I can figure out how to edit the feed -- means I'll kill it, redo it, and resubmit to Apple ... and face the uncertainty of whether it'll be around (with my subscribers) in a few months ...

OR

I could use the naked SoundCloud RSS -- which will definitely work with Apple -- but I will not be able to TAG the feed in any way, nor will I have any idea of subscriber stats. SoundCloud SAYS they plan to add tagging/other RSS functionality "in the next couple of months" ... but will they?

I could use your opinions on what to do. I need to make a decision quickly as I'm holding up a website launch for this.  Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for programming related questions. Have you tried contacting SoundCloud support? http://help.soundcloud.com/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe the actual problem you're having, or give your source and FeedBurner feed URLs, so my advice will be a little blind.

Login to FeedBurner, click on your feed, and go to the "Optimize" tab. Your podcast settings are under "SmartCast." If you're having trouble with your podcast cover art, then the "Image" field is what you need to change.

If this isn't your exact issue, please let us know more details.

Despite the potential doom of FeedBurner (I predict its retirement will be announced in 2013), you *are* right to use FeedBurner if you're using SoundCloud to host your podcast.

SoundCloud is not a podcasting service and it seems that they don't give you full freedom over your RSS feed. This is the lifeblood of your podcast. So using FeedBurner gives you a lot more control than SoundCloud's feed, but you're still sacrificing the control you would have of running your own website.